# java Android reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a project which contais 2 packages.
Now one package P1  has a class A with method mA

Other package P2 has a class B with method mB

i have imported the package P1 in P2

Now when I use replection method

```
Class objClass = Class.forName("A");
```

It says "Class not found" Exception

How to resolve this error? I do not want to use the full name as P1.A

Answer (score 3):

Import does not matter at runtime (and reflection is runtime feature) - it's merely hint to compiler.  Use full qualified class name to  resolve class object